# I can't imgrate data from BigQuery to Data Studio

Tags: google-bigquery, looker-studio

I'm trying to build an automation chart in Data Studio from a scheduled query that I wrote in BigQuery.

When I try to export the table to data I get the next error when I change the column:

[The default](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TYpd4.png)

[The problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vJWaw.png)

Here my query:
[The query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RzNmk.jpg)

Someone has this problem before?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It looks like field `count` has data type as `DATE or DATETIME`, and you are including it as a measure, then you need to apply some measures on data on this field.
Once some transformation logic is applied it will work for you.
As by default these logics are automatically applied on measure filed, but looks like it's not.

[image]

Comment: The count is a data type of date?? how?
I will check it. Thanks